# Is there a way to provide GIT password on the windows command line, and to accept the servers RSA key?

Tags: windows, git

I'm running the GIT client "unattended": that is, it's on a build server, so there's no way of responding "yes" to prompts. I can't log in to the build server as the user that runs the build, and I can't seem to find any /.ssh/ folder to add SSH keys to.

Is there any way to provide the password on the command line? I also need to accept the server's RSA key. In subversion, I can achieve the same thing with the command line switches:

```
--non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username <username> --password <password> --no-auth-cache
```

**Environment:**

Windows 7 64bit

Git (http://git-scm.com/) for Windows (http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)

Server is github.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, there is no straitforward way to do this with the current version of Git. However, you can pull from github.com with the subversion client. [See here](https://github.com/blog/966-improved-subversion-client-support).